# My ncmpcpp and mpd won't work

Tags: mpd, ncmpcpp

For some reason it won't dectect my music and it says Volume N/A and it won't let me change it. You can find my dotfiles [here](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/s52hn8cdic95odq/utlCksZnXe). Yes I am running them locally and let me know if you need some screenshots of the problem.

Thanks in advance -- maybe someone could just give me their config?

Comment: Also see my answer regarding your other mpd/ncmpcpp related question here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/466052/can-someone-help-me-with-my-ncmpcpp-and-mpd Have you tried 'u'-key to update your music library withing ncmpcpp?!

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your audio-output (Volume N/A):

Change the content of your `mpd.conf`, located at `/home/Username/.mpd/mpd.conf` to:

```
music_directory    "/home/nathan/music"  
playlist_directory "/home/nathan/.mpd/playlists"  
db_file            "/home/nathan/.mpd/mpd.db"  
log_file           "/home/nathan/.mpd/mpd.log"  
id_file            "/home/nathan/.mpd/mpd.pid"  
state_file         "/home/nathan/.mpd/mpdstate"  

audio_output {  
      type  "pulse"  
      name  "mpd pulse-audio-output"  
}  

audio_output {  
      type  "alsa"  
      name  "mpd alsamixer-output"  
}  

audio_output {  
type               "fifo"  
name               "fifo_visualizer"
path               "/tmp/mpd.fifo"
format             "44100:16:2"
}
```

After that open a terminal window and type `mpd` + <kbd>enter</kbd>key, followed by `ncmpcpp` + <kbd>enter</kbd>key, then hit <kbd>8</kbd>key, to enter the `Outputs` window (see screenshot), where you then can either choose `mpd pluse-audio-output` or `mpd alsamixer-output`.

One of those two should actually work for you!!

Now for your other problem (It won't dectect my music): Please refer to one of the many guides to set up mpd/ncmpcpp properly: [01](http://www.linuxandlife.com/2012/01/simple-guide-to-set-up-mpd-with-ncmpcpp.html) | [02](http://randalltux.96.lt/2014/01/a-simple-guide-to-setup-mpd-with-ncmpcpp/) |[03](https://www.google.de/#q=ncmpcpp+guides).

If you come across any problems during the setup procedure please edit your original question and specifically add the information there!! GL

[image: image with incorrect spelling of "pulse"]