# Can someone help me with my ncmpcpp and mpd

Tags: mpd, ncmpcpp

Okay, so im running ubuntu 13.10 and my mpd was working fine yesterday and now its not working. So ncmpcpp says volume is at 100% and so does mpc but its playing no sound you can find my dot files [here](https://www.dropbox.com/l/QBkOoPagGmVp8ZW7DBtgpu?) I am running them locally so yeah

Answer (score 0):

You can try with my `mpd.conf` and see if it works for you (I also took the liberty to customize the directories for you, so that you don't have to change them!):

```
music_directory    "/home/nathan/Music"
playlist_directory "/home/nathan/.mpd/playlists"
db_file            "/home/nathan/.mpd/mpd.db"
log_file           "/home/nathan/.mpd/mpd.log"
pid_file           "/home/nathan/.mpd/mpd.pid"
state_file         "/home/nathan/.mpd/mpdstate"

audio_output {
      type  "pulse"
      name  "mpd pluse-audio-output"
 }

#audio_output {
#      type  "alsa"
#      name  "mpd alsamixer-output"
# }

audio_output {
    type                    "fifo"
    name                    "fifo_visualizer"
    path                    "/tmp/mpd.fifo"
    format                  "44100:16:2"
 }
```

1. If `pulse` doesn't work for you, you can always try `alsa` settings. Simply reverse/change `#` comments.
2. In `ncmpcpp` use either [<kbd>8</kbd> and/or <kbd>F8</kbd>: Outputs], to activate/deactivate audio-output, by highlighting it, followed by pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>key!

[image]

Comment: Its still not working

Comment: Before it stopped working, did you change anything in the settings manually or did it just happened out of the blue?! Is your music library/path implemented correctly in both `mpd.conf` and `config` (ncmpcpp directory)?! Also see the `error.log` in ncmpcpp directory for any clues!